# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.

[image: Neil]
[image: Monica]
[image: Michael Kjörling]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

Thanks also to the past pro tempore moderators [Fox Cutter](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/124/fox-cutter), [justkt](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/20/justkt), [Standback](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/1046/standback), and [Mark Baker](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/16226/mark-baker).

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: The mod team has since changed, more info here: [Change in the pro tem mod team](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/646/change-in-the-pro-tem-mod-team?noredirect=1#comment2228_646)

Comment: Standback, thank you for more than *five years* of service to our community!

Comment: @MarkBaker: Welcome to the mod team! And @ all : it's been an absolute pleasure moderating on Writers.SE. I'm still here, and still enjoying :)

Comment: yay @MarkBaker! ::clap::clap::clap::clap::clap::clap::clap::clap::clap::

Comment: Mark Baker, thank you for your service to our community!

Comment: Thank you @MonicaCellio. Glad to help, if only briefly. I am left full of admiration for the work the mods do and the dedication they bring to it. It is harder than it looks. So thank you for your much long and ongoing service.