# Are we short a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Not to name names, or anything, but the good HedgeMage [used to be a mod](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140/moderator-pro-tem-announcement), and I've suddenly noticed that [she](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/111/hedgemage) [isn't](https://writers.stackexchange.com/about).

I'm quite fond both of HedgeMage and of having a full complement of moderators.

- HedgeMage, I hope everything's OK by you?
- Is there a reason we've gone down for 3 mods to 2 with no announcement?
- Do we need to assign a new mod? If so, how does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason she's not a moderator here anymore is because she was hired by StackExchange ([see this blog post for more information](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/welcome-valued-associate-susan-stewart/).

If you (as a community) think that you need more moderators you should just ask the StackExchange Community team. They appoint the pro-tem moderators. This is usually something that the existing pro-tem moderators do, if they need some more help.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know :) Yay HedgeMage! I kind of feel like it would be nice to have a moderator who was more active/present on the site. OTOH, that might require the site to be more active first, and the mods here certainly respond when needed.

Comment: @Standback - I try to be active and certainly am here every day checking things out.

Comment: @justkt: Sorry, I think that was unclear and sounded bad. Didn't mean that :-/ If we're in chat together, I can explain in more detail, but it's really less a criticism and (I suspect) more a side-effect of having such low activity.